# How to add new fragment to actionbar sherlock tabbed fragment layout?

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

[image: Layout]

How Can I add new fragment in actionbarsherlock tabbed fragement layout as shown above? I want to add and show new fragment on "**new**" button click.

Comment: Do you mean you want to add a new tab?

Comment: @RobGThai no. I want to display new fragment/screen which will coverup this whole layout.

Comment: If you want to cover whatever is on screen you will have to do something like:
fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content,myFragment,"MyId");
and you will also have to hide the actionBar.

Comment: You should post your own answer then accept it to keep the 100% going ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this resolve the issue.

```
 fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content,myFragment,"MyId");
```